# How to avoid sending notifications to 'Miscellaneous' channel at Firebase?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-admin

I want to show my notifications in a channel that I create so I can fully customize my channel with my preferences. I'm using a Firebase function to send notifications (messages) from user to user:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotification = functions.firestore.document('/devices/{tokenId}/notifications/{notificationId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        console.log('Push notification event triggered');

        const tokenId = context.params.tokenId;
        const document = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;

        if (document == null) {
            return console.log('A notification has been deleted from database');
        }

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: document.username,
                body: document.message,
                sound: "default"
            },
            data: {
                sender: document.sender
            }
        };
        const options = {
            priority: "high",
            timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 //24 hours
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, payload, options).then(result => {
            console.log('A notification sent to device with tokenId: ', tokenId);
        });
    });
```

I have implemented my FirebaseMessagingService service:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    showNotification(remoteMessage);
}

private void showNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    RemoteMessage.Notification remoteNotification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    if (remoteNotification == null) return;
    String title = remoteNotification.getTitle();
    String message = remoteNotification.getBody();

    Notification notification;
    Notification.Builder builder = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O ?
            new Notification.Builder(this, CH_MESSAGE) : new Notification.Builder(this);

    notification = builder
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setCategory(CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

And created my own notification channel at my Application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    createNotificationChannels();
}

private void createNotificationChannels() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (notificationManager == null) return;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CH_MESSAGE,
                getString(R.string.messages), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationChannel.setDescription(getString(R.string.message_channel_description));

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
}
```

I can successfully send notifications, but notifications are going to Miscellaneous channel.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to remove the channel by using its channel ID with `notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel("fcm_fallback_notification_channel");`, but it still recreates the channel and sends the notification there. How can I remove Miscellaneous channel permanently and handle my notifications with my own channels?

Comment: *To answer the title of the question:, "How to avoid sending notifications to 'Miscellaneous' channel at Firebase?"* Set a default channel for FCM messages and they will be sent there instead of `miscellaneous`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the problem I am facing, my message payload contains both notification and data fields. According to [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) my messages were not calling `onMessageReceived` method when app is in background. Now I'm using only data payload which calls the method when app is at both background and foreground.

```
const payload = {
    data: {
        sender: document.sender,
        username: document.username,
        message: document.message
    }
};
```

And in my `onMessageReceived` method:

```
Map<String, String> remoteMap = remoteMessage.getData();
String senderUid = remoteMap.get("sender");
String senderUsername = remoteMap.get("username");
String message = remoteMap.get("message");

Notification.Builder builder = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O ?
        new Notification.Builder(this, CH_MESSAGE) : new Notification.Builder(this);

Notification notification = builder
        .setContentTitle(senderUsername)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_message)
        .build();

notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: I think technically, the "correct" solution is to read the data from the intent extras, but it seems much nicer to just avoid implementing more logic to read the intent extras, like you have done.